# How to write in different places of an XML file at once

Tags: c++, xml, kml

I am writing a C++ class that writes data to a [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/) file on the fly.

The problem is that I need to write several [`<Point>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point) items inside a [`<Folder>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#folder) and  at the same time a [`<LineString>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) item to generate a path connecting these points.

```
My KML
├── Points
|   ├── Point 1
|   ├── Point 2
|   ├── Point 3
|   └── ...
|
└── Path
```

Since I must do this on the fly, I need to find a way of writing in different parts of the KML file, so that I don't mess up the XML document structure.

For example, say that we have 2 points:

1. First record Point 1 on the file:

```xml
      <Placemark>
        <name>Point 1</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>11.807993,48.171485,536.15</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
```

2. Then add its coordinates to the path at the end of the file:

```xml
    <Placemark>
      <name>Path</name>
      <LineString>
        <coordinates>
          11.807993,48.171485,536.15
        </coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```

3. Now record Point 2:

```xml
      <Placemark>
        <name>Point 2</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>11.807978,48.171473,538.92</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
```

4. and add its coordinates to the path at the end:

```xml
    <Placemark>
      <name>Path</name>
      <LineString>
        <coordinates>
          11.807993,48.171485,536.15
          11.807978,48.171473,538.92
        </coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
```

And so on...

And this is what the resulting KML file would look like:

[image: KML in Google Earth]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>My KML</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Points</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Point 1</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>11.807993,48.171485,536.15</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Point 2</name>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>11.807978,48.171473,538.92</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Path</name>
      <LineString>
        <coordinates>
          11.807993,48.171485,536.15
          11.807978,48.171473,538.92
        </coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

This is just a simplified example. In my real scenario, I will have to do this with thousands/millions of points. But the concept is the same as above.

Since my code is meant to run on devices with very scarce/constrained memory resources, I can't afford using solutions that involve building some kind of tree structure in memory and then serializing it to XML.

How should I approach this in C++?

EDIT:

Answering the comments about resources, I can't give any specific numbers, but the bottleneck on the target machine will be memory for sure, that's why I can't afford to keep all the coordinates in memory for later printing. I must print each pair of coordinates one by one (in an [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) fashion) reusing that same memory space for the next pair of coordinates, so that at any given moment there is only one pair of coordinates in memory.

EDIT:

I guess the conclusion I can come up with is:

Since writing in different locations of the same file seems complex and error-prone<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180414/how-to-write-in-different-places-of-an-xml-file-at-once#comment93251008_53180414)</sup>, writing to 2 different files first and then combine them later<sup>[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180414/how-to-write-in-different-places-of-an-xml-file-at-once#comment93251284_53180414)</sup> seems the approach to go for.

Comment: Growing a file in the middle is going to require you to read in everything after the insertion point, overwrite with the new data, and then write everything back that was after the insertion point.

Comment: is it possible to write to different files and combine them at the end?

Comment: @StephanLechner yes, that would be a possible solution I'm looking into.

Comment: "very scarce/constrained memory resources" how scarce?

Comment: Writing to multiple locations in the same file *at the same time* is very difficult.  Most hard drive interfaces are serial and they only write to one sector of one track at a time.  You have to reposition the head (a.k.a. seek) to another position in order to write to a different place in the file.

Comment: Files are sequential, much like that old fashioned tape stuff.  There is no way to *insert* into the middle of a file (similar to an array).  In order to insert into the middle, the stuff after the insertion point has to be moved down.  A more efficient (and common) method is to write to a new file.

Comment: You have to be much more specific about your constraints, you clearly have some in mind, to make the question answerable.

Comment: @PasserBy I've edited the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.